# Reading a csv file with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, csv

I am trying to convert a Java program I had written to read a csv file into a Spring Boot Application but keep getting a NullPointerException. I just want to print out the contents of the csv file.
Here is the code:

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
   <bean id="Assembler" class="sample.spring.chapter01.Assembler">          
        <property name="infopieces" value="classpath:1erelistearticle2.csv"></property>         
   </bean>
   <bean id="PieceDAO" class="sample.spring.chapter01.PieceDAO">
        <property name="listp" ref="Piece"></property>
    </bean>
   <bean id = "Piece" class = "sample.spring.chapter01.Piece"/>   
</beans>
```

Minapp.java

```
package sample.spring.chapter01;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class MinApp {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MinApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        Resource resource =context.getResource("classpath:1erelistearticle2.csv");

        Assembler obj=(Assembler) context.getBean("Assembler");


        obj.display();

        try {
            ArrayList<Piece> listp=obj2.getList();
            for (Piece p:listp) {
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        } catch (IOException ef) {



    }
}
```

Assembler.java

```
package sample.spring.chapter01;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class Assembler {
    private PieceDAO listp;
    //private CSVParser parser;
    private Resource infopieces;

    public void setlistp(PieceDAO lp) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        fill();     
    }

    public void setinfopieces(Resource csvFile){
        this.infopieces = csvFile;
    }

    public PieceDAO getlistp() {
        return listp;
    }

    public CSVParser getinfocsv() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
         //   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("classpath:1erelistearticle.csv"));

            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("classpath:1erelistearticle.csv"));

            InputStream is=infopieces.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));              

            //ClassLoader classloader=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            //InputStream is=classloader.getResourceAsStream("classpath:1erelistearticle.csv");
            //CSVReader cr=new CSVReader(is);
            CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader().parse(br);
            //CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader().parse(is);
            //for (CSVRecord record: parser) {
            //    System.out.println(record.get("référence ascensoriste"));
            //}
            return parser;
    }

    public void fill() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        CSVParser parser=getinfocsv();
        for (CSVRecord record:parser) {
            String ref=record.get("référence ascensoriste").trim();
            String asc=record.get("ascensoriste").trim();
            String desc=record.get("Description article").trim();                
            String prix=record.get("Pv");
            String category=record.get("Familie").trim();
            //System.out.println(category);
            Piece lift_comp=new Piece();
            lift_comp.setasc(asc);
            lift_comp.setdesc(desc);
            lift_comp.setref(ref);
            lift_comp.setprice(prix);
            lift_comp.settype(category);
            lift_comp.setinfo();
            listp.addPiece(lift_comp);
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        listp.output();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls mention on which line you are getting exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of problems with the code. I guess the first one is

The call

```
obj.display();
```

which calls `listp.output();` but the `listp` is never assigned. neither from config nor from code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have assigned the listp variable correctly and everything works ok. You mentioned plenty of problems with the code. Could you specify? Thanks

Comment: You fixed some of the issues. But actually it's better to Autowire the resource into the PieceDAO rather than assigning from outside. It's not thread safe when you assign the resource in the mid of processing previous one. You can just print whole list. No need to iterate it's elements. I don't see why in the `Piece getlistp(Piece p)` method you check by equals() can't you cal contains()?

Comment: That's true. But I didn't think I was allowed to open a spring container outside the main method (It seems I need this to load the resource with the command Resource resource =context.getResource("classpath:1erelistearticle2.csv");

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. The classes and beans.xml are as below and read the csv file using the Spring framework.

Beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="PieceDAO" class="sample.spring.chapter01.PieceDAO">
        <property name="listp" ref="Piece"></property>              
   </bean>
   <bean id = "Piece" class = "sample.spring.chapter01.Piece"/>   
</beans>
```

Minapp.java

package sample.spring.chapter01;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class MinApp {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MinApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        Resource resource =context.getResource("classpath:1erelistearticle2.csv");

        PieceDAO obj=(PieceDAO) context.getBean("PieceDAO");
        obj.fill(resource);
        obj.display();

    }
}
```

PieceDAO.java

```
package sample.spring.chapter01;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PieceDAO {
    private List<Piece> listp;
    //private Resource resource;

    public PieceDAO() {


    }

    public void setlistp(Piece p) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        listp=new ArrayList<Piece>();
        //this.fill(resource);
    }

    public Piece getlistp(Piece p) {
        for (Piece currp:listp) {
            if (currp.equals(p)) {
                return currp;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }


    public void fill(Resource resource) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        InputStream is=resource.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));              


        CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader().parse(br);

        for (CSVRecord record:parser) {
            String ref=record.get("référence ascensoriste").trim();
            String asc=record.get("ascensoriste").trim();
            String desc=record.get("Description article").trim();                
            String prix=record.get("Pv");
            String category=record.get("Familie").trim();
            //System.out.println(category);
            Piece lift_comp=new Piece();
            lift_comp.setasc(asc);
            lift_comp.setdesc(desc);
            lift_comp.setref(ref);
            lift_comp.setprice(prix);
            lift_comp.settype(category);
            lift_comp.setinfo();
            listp.add(lift_comp);
        }


    }

    public void display() {
        for (Piece p:listp) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

}
```